# How to use the Signatures in an error report?

Tags: c#, exception

I just sent out a program for beta testing and a user got back to me with this Error Report:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   myprogram.exe (not the actual name of the file)
Problem Signature 02:   1.4.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   4ff759ce
Problem Signature 04:   System.Windows.Forms
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4ee9b94f
Problem Signature 07:   14e0
Problem Signature 08:   23
Problem Signature 09:   System.ObjectDisposedException
```

I can of course find information on the [System.ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1aayk129.aspx) at MSDN. So I probably have some problem where I ask for an object that has been disposed (probably a filestream).

So Signature 09: tells me what kind of Exception it has thrown - but will the other signatures give me any information on what has caused this exception?

To me Problem Signature 06-08 seem to hold interesting data, but I don't know what it means.

It ought to be of rather general interest how to read one of these error reports.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The information on the problem signature is basically memory positions for the faulting dll at an intermediate language level.

[This blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316200009/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx) post explain each of the available fields.
You can inspect the dll by using [MSIL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Hope this is what you were looking for,

Regards,

EDIT: As an additional note, in order to investigate intermediate level code I found easier to do File->Dump in the MSIL Disassembler.
Then search for the method according to the Signature 07 param. e.g. .method /.*590.*/